# Creating dataframes using a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create dataframes that are frequency tables by group.

Below I'm creating the summary tables for the columns use and ehr.

```
use_df <- w1w2 %>% 
  group_by(wave, use) %>% 
  summarise(cnt_use = n()) %>%
  drop_na(use) %>%
  mutate(perc_use = case_when(
    wave == "W1" ~ cnt_use / sum(cnt_use),
    wave == "W2" ~ cnt_use / sum(cnt_use)))


ehr_df <- w1w2 %>% 
  group_by(wave, ehr) %>% 
  summarise(cnt_ehr = n()) %>%
  drop_na(ehr) %>%
  mutate(perc_ehr = case_when(
    wave == "W1" ~ cnt_ehr / sum(cnt_ehr),
    wave == "W2" ~ cnt_ehr / sum(cnt_ehr)))
```

the datasets look like

[use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to877.png)
[ehr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YXKR.png)

I have tried and I get an error.

```
summary_fn <- function(var_name, df) {
  
  varname <- enquo(varname)
  
  df_!!varname %>% 
    group_by(wave, !!var_name) %>% 
    summarise(cnt_!!var_name := n()) %>%
    drop_na(!!var_name) %>%
    mutate(perc_!!var_name := case_when(
      wave == "W1" ~ cnt_!!var_name / sum(cnt_!!var_name),
      wave == "W2" ~ cnt_!!var_name / sum(cnt_!!var_name)))
  
  view(df_!!varname)

}


summary_fn(use, w1w2)
```

What am I missing? Your help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your data using `dput()` if possible? It makes it easier for others to run your code. Can you also share some information about what errors you get?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, the first part of the code works, but the second doesn't? If that is the case, it's probably due to ``!!varname`` in the wrong places, e.g., ``df_!!varname``

Comment: @nrennie, pardon my being a newb, I can do that, but the dput() code would be some 100 rows of data to replicate a sample dataset. Would such large piece of code be ok to be pasted here? Please let me know.

Comment: @runr that's correct. Since I'm getting familiar with Tidy Eval, I'm having a hard time, creating a function that would do the 1st part programmatically, since I have more columns to replicate.

Comment: It should be find but you could add a subset of your data e.g. the first 10 observation using `head()` and `dput()` instead.